# Is it possible to write a Debugger Visualizer for Visual Studio 2010 to display 64-bit .NET programs?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, 32bit-64bit

Is it possible to write a Debugger Visualizer for Visual Studio 2010 to display data of 64-bit .NET programs?

I already write them for 32-bit programming, but I can't manage to use or compile them for use with 64-bit applications. Any suggestions?

Comment: "I can't manage to use or compile them for use with 64-bit applications" - why, what happens? Isn't the attribute part of the .NET framework - how can it not compile? And, I'm reluctant to say it, but can't you use a more recent Visual Studio with better 64-bit support, e.g. you should be able to use VS2013 Community if you're not a large enterprise?

Comment: When I activate the Visualizer, a BadImageFormatException occurs in a JIT debugger window. The Visualizer loads a DLL (which loads a C++ dll also). But the 64-bit data cannot be handled by the Visualizer. An exception occurs. The Visualizer itself has been compiled 64 bit. Does it has something to do with the fact that VS is 32-bit? We are still using 2010. We are just testing 2013 at the moment when we have the time, not using it everyday yet.

Comment: The most obvious explanation is that this C++ DLL is a 32-bit executable.  You'll have to provide a 64-bit build of it.

Comment: you have  2 choices the one mentioned by @HansPassant  the other one is to target 32 bit for all your application don't worry as windows will handle this for u by the WOW

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through the same issue. I use Visual Studio 2013 and our project at work is 64 bit. I built a 64 bit version of my custom visualizer and placed it into the Visual Studio installation folder as per [MSDN walk-through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb2yca43.aspx).

I think because Visual Studio is a 32 bit process, it cannot load the 64-bit targeted assembly. As a result you see the JIT exception in the dialog box.

It'll come a day that they'll simply have to release a 64-bit build - I hope! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the visualizer and the type you want to visualize in a separate assembly compiled with the Any CPU platform.

The visualizer is shown by Visual Studio, which is an x86 process, so it can not load an assembly built for an x64 platform.