# How to install Visual Studio 2017 64bit version explicitly?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have 64bit windows 10 machine .When downloading and installing visual studio, I didn't see any step to select the version which is 32bit or 64bit. Implicitly installer takes the installation path as :

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio**

And after installation it is showing as a 32bit version in task manager.

Comment: What do you mean by "version which is 32bit or 64bit"?  The IDE which runs as a 32-bit platform process will build and debug both 32-bit and 64-bit processes on a 64-bit system

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 is still a 32Bit application, Microsoft tried to defend their decision to not provide VS as 64bit in [various blog posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2015/12/29/revisiting-64-bit-ness-in-visual-studio-and-elsewhere/).

So by default 32Bit applications install to `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and everything is ok what you see.

// Update

The next [Visual Studio Version 2022, will be 64Bit](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022/) to fix the out of memory issues:

> The next major release of Visual Studio will be faster, more
> approachable, and more lightweight, designed for both learners and
> those building industrial scale solutions. **For the first time ever,
> Visual Studio will be 64-bit.**
> Visual Studio 2022 will be a 64-bit application, no longer limited to ~4gb of memory in the main devenv.exe process. With a 64-bit Visual Studio on Windows, you can open, edit, run, and debug even the biggest and most complex solutions without running out of memory.

Comment: Note that there are x64 native versions of the compiler toolchain and linker. For the VS IDE project system, you can enable this by using a property ``<PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture>`` or setting an environment variable ``set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64``

Comment: Unfortunately for Microsoft, with the plethora of performance issues Visual Studio has, their position is frankly indefensible. Lots of software companies (including the one I work at) have big solutions (more than 20 projects), and those run horribly with the minute amount of memory a 32-bit process can use.

Comment: @TomLint I understand your pain. submit feedback so that Microsoft creates a 64bit VS

Comment: Another issue with trying to run Visual Studio in 32 bit when building 64-bit applications is that one cannot make use of custom data visualizers.  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110880/is-it-possible-to-write-a-debugger-visualizer-for-visual-studio-2010-to-display

Comment: @TomLint check my update with the link to blog about VS2022, this version will be 64bit to solve this.