# Why does Visual Studio try to install to Program Files (x86)?

Tags: visual-studio

When I started the installer for VS 2017 the default installation directory was set to Program Files (x86). I am using Windows 10 x64 OS on a 64 bit machine. 
I downloaded from this link https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/. I just want make sure I am installing the right thing before proceeding.

Comment: Because it's a 32-bit IDE, and that's where 32-bit applications are installed.

Comment: I selected the x64 English version at the download screen. I also ended up with install in program files (x86). Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.9.9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Visual Studio 2017 64bit version explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360738/how-to-install-visual-studio-2017-64bit-version-explicitly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the program is a 32-bit version, and you have a 64-bit version of Windows.

You have downloaded the 32-bit version and that's why its going to that folder. If you were to download a 64-bit version of Visual Studio<sup>(a)</sup>, it would be placed (by default) in to "Program Files".

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Unfortunately [no such beast exists](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version-yet/), so VS will always end up in the `x86` variant unless you explicitly put it elsewhere. In other words, what you're seeing is *totally* normal.