# Since SSDT is now available in 64 bit, does that mean we can use the 64 bit Excel driver?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Lots of articles about ACE driver not found, running in 32 bit, etc. etc. and it all ends up with SSDT is a 32 bit IDE and therefore you need to use the 32 bit driver. The articles are old. It looks like there's a 64 bit SQL Server Data Tools on MSDN. Has anybody tried to use SSDT 64 bit to build an SSIS package that uses the 64 bit Excel driver. I'm thinking maybe we no longer have to remove the 64 bit drivers and install the Microsoft Access 2010 redistributable to get the 32 bit drivers and run our packages as 32 bit.

Comment: This is a rats nest. VS as an application is 32-bit and Microsoft has no plans to upgrade it to 64-bit that I am aware of. But, VS can compile solutions in 64-bit. My understanding is that the 32-bit runtime mode for SSIS packages is for custom components that are compiled as such. Where are you seeing SSDT for 64-bit?

Comment: in the msdn subscription, search for SQL Server Data Tools and you'll see the February 2015 edition. On the drop down it shows, x64 and x86. Same thing if you search for Visual Studio. Is it possible that the installer is 64 bit but the program itself is 32 bit?

Comment: I see. I did not download SSDT through the MSDN subscription, I just went straight to the SSDT site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). I think you are correct, it is an installer for the bit-type of SQL Server that you are running. So, I would choose the corresponding bit-type. Other than that, I do not believe there is any change to connection managers and such, as you mentioned in your OP.

Comment: You got me thinking so I did another search and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137486/why-does-visual-studio-try-to-install-to-program-files-x86. It looks like you are correct. Thank you

Comment: I went ahead and posted the comments as the answer for other users to see. It might be helpful for others to see this question marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rats nest. Visual Studio, the application itself, is 32-bit and Microsoft has no plans to upgrade it to 64-bit that I am aware of. But, VS can compile solutions in 64-bit. My understanding is that the 32-bit runtime mode for SSIS packages is for custom components that are compiled as such.

I did not download SSDT through the MSDN subscription, I just went straight to the SSDT site (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/…). I think you are correct, it is an installer for the bit-type of SQL Server that you are running. So, I would choose the corresponding bit-type. Other than that, I do not believe there is any change to connection managers and such, as you mentioned in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

With SSDT installed, in Visual Studio (2017 or 2019) you can ONLY use Excel 32 bit drivers from [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) since Visual Studio is a 32 bit application. You CANNOT use 64 bit Excel drivers if running an SSIS package from Visual Studio IDE.

To use the Excel 64 bit driver, install the corresponding bit excel driver from the link above and use the 64 bit DTEXEC.exe via command line (not Visual Studio). Example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.exe /f C:\package.dtsx
```

This give you a larger memory space to load large excels. You can install the 32 bit and 64 bit Excel drivers side by side (and no you do not need to install Office).

And the important bit here is that the 64 bit DTExec.exe is present ONLY when installing it via SQL Server installation (NOT Visual Studio). It should be at least Developer edition and upwards. The 64 bit DTExec.exe  is not present when installing Visual Studio (even if Enterprise edition).

So you develop SSIS packages in the IDE using 32 bit excel drivers and run in production using the 64 bit Excel drivers using 64 bit DTExec.exe via command line.